# Python FTP Most Recent File

Tags: python, ftp

How do I determine the most recently modified file from an ftp directory listing? I used the max function on the unix timestamp locally, but the ftp listing is harder to parse. The contents of each line is only separated by a space.

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('ftp.cwi.nl')
ftp.login()
data = []
ftp.dir(data.append)
ftp.quit()
for line in data:
    print line
```

output:

```
drwxrwsr-x   5 ftp-usr  pdmaint     1536 Mar 20 09:48 .
dr-xr-srwt 105 ftp-usr  pdmaint     1536 Mar 21 14:32 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 ftp-usr  pdmaint     5305 Mar 20 09:48 INDEX
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to make some corrections:

```
date_str = ' '.join(line.split()[5:8])
time.strptime(date_str, '%b %d %H:%M') # import time
```

And to find the most recent file

```
for line in data:
    col_list = line.split()
    date_str = ' '.join(line.split()[5:8])
    if datePattern.search(col_list[8]):
        file_dict[time.strptime(date_str, '%b %d %H:%M')] = col_list[8]
        date_list = list([key for key, value in file_dict.items()])
s = file_dict[max(date_list)]
print s
```

Answer (score 4):

If the FTP server supports the `MLSD` command (and quite possibly it does), you can use the `FTPDirectory` class from [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867217/how-to-delete-files-with-a-python-script-from-a-ftp-server-which-are-older-than-7/3114477#3114477) answer in a related question.

Create an `ftplib.FTP` instance (eg aftp) and an `FTPDirectory` instance (eg aftpdir), connect to the server, `.cwd` to the directory you want, and read the files using `aftpdir.getdata(aftp)`. After that, you get name of the freshest file as:

```
import operator

max(aftpdir, key=operator.attrgetter('mtime')).name
```

Answer (score 2):

To parse the date, you can use (from version 2.5 onwards):

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('Mar 21 14:32', '%b %d %H:%M')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split each line and get the date:

```
date_str = ' '.join(line.split(' ')[5:8])
```

Then parse the date (check out egenix [mxDateTime](http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/mxDateTime/) package, specifically the `DateTimeFromString` function) to get comparable objects.